# How to declare a auto-incrementing alphanumerical id field with predefined aplphabetic part (Django python)

Tags: python, django, django-models, auto-increment, autofield

I am developing an app in Django.

I want to insert in my model an auto-incrementing alphanumerical ID field, having, by default, a fixed alphabetical part and an auto-incrementing numerical part.
But I also want the availability to change, from admin section, this id to another alphanumerical one, with a different alphanumerical and numerical part.
**Please note:** I don't want to overwrite the django default id field, I just want to include in my model a field that gets as default value an auto-incrementing alphanumerical value.

Example of what I want:

- Desired alphabetical constant part: ITM
- Desired numerical auto-incrementing part: 00000

  So that every object of my model, when generated, get default
  progressive values like: ITM00001, ITM00002, ITM00003, ...
- Also, I would like to be able to change the field value from my admin
  section into values like ABC0000001, DFG0051, RST034, ...
- Max field length: 10  (It can be also higher)

I realize that I have to use `AutoField` and to somehow join the constant string with the auto-incrementing numerical variable, but I don't know how to do it.

```
class my_model(models.Model):

    Field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    static_ID = models.AutoField(???)
```

What code should I write to get a field with the features I described upwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

Since I don't need a specific length for my id, nor a constant increment between two consecutive ids, I can use `time.time()` to get a unique time number every time the object in the model is created. Then I can turn that time number into a string and concatenate it with a constant prefix.

In **models.py**:

```
import time

def return_timestamped_id():
    prefix = "ITCH"     
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()*10000000))
    default_value = prefix + timestamp
    return(default_value)


class my_model(models.Model):        
    Field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    static_ID = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, default=return_timestamped_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing it, why not using a property method to generate that id? For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    
    @property
    def static_id(self):
        'ITM{0:07d}'.format(self.pk)
```

If you are concerned with filtering, then you can use [custom manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers):

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_id(self, static_id):
        return int(static_id[2:])
    def filter_static_id(self, static_id):
        _id = self.get_id(static_id)
        return self.filter(pk=_id)
    
  def filter_static_id(self, static_id):
        _id = self.get_id(static_id)
        return self.get(pk=_id)

 class MyModel(models.Model):
      objects = CustomManager()
```

Comment: This class MyModel(models.Model):

    field_one = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def static_id(self):
        'ITM{0:07d}'.format(self.pk)

Makes me run into error:

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (static_id) specified for my_model

Comment: Where do you get the error? Can you add the full error stactrace?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can split your field into three separate fields:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    PREF = "ITM"
    NUMS = 5

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    pref = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=PREF)  # prefix that has defaul value and can be modified
    nums = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=NUMS)  # the number of digits
    static_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)  # auto increment field

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('pref', 'nums', 'static_id')

    @property
    def static_key(self):
        return self.pref + str(self.static_id).zfill(self.nums)
```

Comment: I run into error

assert not cls._meta.auto_field, "Model %s can't have more than one AutoField." % cls._meta.label
AssertionError: Model my_app.my_model can't have more than one AutoField.

Apparently, each django model must have no more than one AutoField
so I am forced to set 

static_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

Comment: I prefer not to follow this path because by overwriting the django default id often generates problems with managing that id by the admin.